# How to check whether user is present in the database or not using Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, postman

I stuck in writing the logic to check whether the user presents in the database or not...

Here I am sharing the important information regarding my problem for better understanding.

1. My API Link :

```
http://localhost:8081/Metadata/api/user/IsValidUser
```

2. Postman, post JSON request

```
 {

    "Contact_No" : 9876543210,
    "Password" : "pass@12345"
}
```

Here in postman, I am writing the data manually. but for actual data, I have created the login form in angular
3. Now it will check the above data is present in the database or not. If present then I will get the below information.

[Login screen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBtHI.png)

```
{
    "program": null,
    "version": null,
    "dateTime": null,
    "success": true,
    "errorCode": null,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "message": "User Authenticated Successfully",
    "data": {
        "mobile_No": 9876543210,
        "isValid": true,
        "pSNL": {
            "first_Name": "First",
            "middle_Name": "",
            "last_Name": "Buyer",
            "address": null,
            "village": "Airoli",
            "taluka": "Thane",
            "district": "Thane",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "pincode": 400708,
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "dob": "06-01-1999"
        }
    }
}
```

4. I wrote the service in angular, but I think its required **password parameter as well** I am a little confused here. Like how to write a Post request with two parameters.

```
 IsValidUser(validUser : IsValidUserModel){
    console.log("Calling IsValidUser API " + validUser.Contact_No);
    return this.http.post("/Metadata/api/user/IsValidUser", validUser)
    
  }
```

5. IsValidUserModel.ts

```
export class IsValidUserModel {

    Contact_No: number
    Password: string
}
```

Now let me summarized my query, All I want to make check whether the user is present or not in the database. But I am confused about how to do the implementation. Can anyone suggest to me the best way to implement my problem or how to tackle the type of challenge in angular? I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if this example helps    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firestore-check-if-value-exist

Comment: Thanx for the effort, but I need to post a request service.

Comment: You mentioned you were using angular 3, do you use the HttpModule or the HttpClientModule? If you're not sure, just edit your post to include the constructor of your service. There should be a line that either looks like this `private http:Http` (old HttpModule) or like this `private http:HttpClient` (newer HttpClientModule). The API changed between these two, so we need that information to help. Additionally, to sent the request you have to keep in mind that you need to subscribe to the observable. Angular will only make the request on subscription!

Comment: @pascalpuetz sorry I guess I made a typo, I am using angular 10 not 3